# My program broken at the end of function _CrtIsValidHeapPointer. What's happened?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, stdstring

In my program, I used `std::string` as a static global variable. When I called a function like this:

```
void NXMonitor::print(const string &msg) {
    if(! lw->IsOpen() ) lw->Open();
    lw->WriteLine(msg); }
```

The `lw` is an class as listing window. The break was at `lw->WriteLine(msg)`. The declaration of member function `WriteLine` is:

```
public:viod WriteLine(const NXString &msg);
```

And the `NXString` has an constructor like this:

```
NXString(const std::string &text, NXStringMode mode = Locale);
```

My IDE is **MS VS 2005**. I used **/MD** as runtime library. The information of MS VS 2005 as follow:

> Unhandled exception at 0x20502531 in ugraf.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.

The breakpoint was at the end of `function _CrtIsValidHeapPointer`.
So what's the problem? How can I fixed it?

Comment: I think it would be easier to understand your issue if you'll provide some code

Comment: I have add some information about the problem.

Comment: I think problem is somewhere before `WriteLine` call. For example you corrupt memory that contains your string.

Comment: But you can see, before calling `WriteLine`, I just do nothing. I think problem is setting of the project. But I don't where.

Comment: So after program starts you just call `void NXMonitor::print(const string &msg)`? And you never assign any value for static string that was mentioned?

Comment: If the problem is only in settings, your solution will be creating new project inside another IDE (or another IDE version). But it seems that problem in code

Comment: I found the problem. Before I called `print`. I used `stringstream` like this `cTimeToString(ctime_start, ss);theNXMonitor->print(ss.str());ss.str("");`. The problem occurred when I called this `print`. I don't know whether do l need to call `ss.clear()` before I reuse the `ss`. I have called `ss.str("")` to clear the `ss`.

Comment: Otherwise, there was no problem at MS VS 2013 using the same code.